# How to hook into woocommerce cart table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hook into the woocommerce cart table, to be more precize, I want to add a label nearby the coupon code.

What hook can I use to append after the coupon code (in the cart table) my custom label?

These are the hooks I've tried so far:

```
woocommerce_coupon_loaded (action)

woocommerce_cart_coupon (action)

woocommerce_applied_coupon (action)

woocommerce_coupon_code (filter)
```

But none of these works.

Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you use that ? Because `woocommerce_cart_coupon` working fine for me.

Comment: in this way: add_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'test');
function  test()
{
    echo "<span style='background:red !important;padding:10px;color:white;'>test!</span>";
}

And the echo is nearby the products list table, not on the cart totals table

Comment: can you show it with a screenshot where is it coming and where do you want it ?

Comment: ok i found that the filter to use is woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_label.
Thanks anyway guys!